# SYN and SYN+ACK not blocked by firewall

Tags: tcp, kernel, firewall

I came across this scenario :

I have blocked all my INBOUND ports , excepting (tcp 53 and udp 53 - DNS , 2 internals ip classes, and ICMP) and I tried to connect to google without succes which is good. But, using a packet capture software (Microsoft Network Monitor and Wireshark) I saw that the SYN packets and SYN+ACK response pachets are not blocked. But my computer won't send the 3rd ACK packet so the connection won;t be established.

Why is that ?

Platform : Windows 2003 Server using Internal Firewall (IP Routing)

Comment: You'll have to give more info - platform, firewall software and its configuration. Also, the question probably belongs on serverfault.com

Comment: Windows 2003 Server - Internal firewall (IP Route)

Comment: The status quo makes sense to me if you are sniffing on the outside interface of the firewall. You blocked a bunch of stuff INBOUND. So the outbound SYN goes out untouched, the SYN|ACK comes back and you can see it on the packet capture but it's subsequently blocked by the firewall. Your computer never gets the SYN|ACK so it never sends the final ACK to establish the connection.

Comment: Yes ... thanks .. now i understood it. you're right, the capture software capture's it even if it's dropped later by firewall .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered in a comment by Celada.

> The status quo makes sense to me if you are sniffing on the outside
>   interface of the firewall. You blocked a bunch of stuff INBOUND. So
>   the outbound SYN goes out untouched, the SYN|ACK comes back and you
>   can see it on the packet capture but it's subsequently blocked by the
>   firewall. Your computer never gets the SYN|ACK so it never sends the
>   final ACK to establish the connection.